# in an Asp.Net core application, Unable to read the connection string from the json file?

Tags: asp.net-core, database-connection

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-strings?

I followed this site to put a connection string in a json file but when I try to access the database say I want to get the list of all the Hotels, I get the exception "Value cannot be null"

```cs
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("ConnectionServerJson.json")
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();

    configuration = builder.Build();
}

public IConfiguration configuration { get; set; }

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    services.AddDbContext<DBRezervareHotelieraContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddScoped<DbContext>(sp => sp.GetService<DBRezervareHotelieraContext>());
    var container = services.BuildServiceProvider();

    services.AddMvc();
}
```

this is the connectionStringJson.json file

```js
{
  "connectionString": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=DESKTOP-TPPITPA\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=DBRezervareHoteliera;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  }
}
```

I also did take out from the context class `DBRezervareHotelieraContext` the `onConfigure` method and put the following 
 public

```cs
DBRezervareHotelieraContext(DbContextOptions<DBRezervareHotelieraContext> options) : base(options)
{

}
```

I don't think this matter but might be helpful

Comment: You have shown *connection**String**Json.json* but the file you add (via `AddJson`) is *Connection**Server**Json.json* - typo?

Comment: The proper name of the key is "ConnectionStrings" with "s" on the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a "s" on the end of "ConnectionString" in your config file: `ConnectionStrings` and just for the case name it PascalCase.